# How to find the right commit to apply a patch?

Tags: git, kernel, patch

I am working with Buildroot on an embedded system. I have to apply a kernel patch, but I wasn't told which commit I had to patch. I am not even 100% sure about the repo... Does the patch file contain the "from" commit hash ?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually it's not. You may take a look on the patch and check this yourself, a patch is a text file of a clean human-readable format w/o any significant magic. You may clone a local copy of the kernel repository and try to find a commit with context: check what lines are unchanged in the patch and then try to locate those lines in the kernel sourcetree/history

Comment: This question doesn't really make much sense.  In general, you apply a patch to something you're building, not to a specific commit.  You might apply it to a specific commit in order to form a new branch starting with that patch and continuing, but in that case, whoever you're collaborating with should tell you where to start, probably by creating that branch in whatever repo you're sharing.